# jquery hide method hides div but then div reappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide

I have the following code where I want to hide the closest grouping div.  When I click the delete button, the div disappears but then comes back (added 600 so I could see this).

I have researched and found others saying to use event.preventDefault, return false; and add href”#!’ to the `<a>` tag.  None seem to work.  I changed the `.hide()` to `.remove()` and It works, but I won't just want to hide the div and use it later in the post model binding

```
@model Durendal.Core.ViewModels.RoleViewModel
<div class="d-flex flex-row grouping">
    <div class="flex-grow-1" style="overflow-x: auto;">
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Id)
                    .DataTextField("Name")
                    .DataValueField("Id")
                    .MinLength(3)
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" })
                    .Height(290)
                    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                    .AutoWidth(true)
                    .DataSource(source =>
                    {
                        source.Custom()
                            .Transport(transport => transport
                                .Read(read => read
                                    .Action("GetRoles", "DataApi", new { Area = "Shared" })));
                    })
        )
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <a href="#!" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger waves-effect remove-grouping-button">
            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            $('.remove-grouping-button').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).closest('.grouping').hide(600);
                return false;
            });
        })();
    </script>
</div>
```

This should hide the div but it reappears

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57523873/edit) then `[<>]` snippet editor. Remove your templating and post a [mcve] with ONLY HTML, JS and CSS - Use view-source and remove unnecessary code from the example. Your code SHOULD work so some OTHER code makes it re-appear

Comment: Hi @Deke Darsey, remove  event.preventDefault(); and try again,

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda That would not be a good idea. It is to stop the link from executing

Answer (score 1):

Your code works - some other code must make it re-appear.

I only post this for demonstration and will delete it when you have seen it.

Please do not vote up or accept as answer and No need to vote down either

```js
$(function() {
  $('.remove-grouping-button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // cancel anchor click
    $(this).closest('.grouping').hide(600);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex flex-row grouping">
  <div class="flex-grow-1" style="overflow-x: auto;">
   Some Kendo dropdown
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <a href="#!" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger waves-effect remove-grouping-button">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```